# KeyBoardHookProc is not being invoked from Excel VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba, winapi

I am trying to capture the keypress event. Below is the code. If I press say for example 'F8' from anywhere, the method 'HookCallback' is being called. But If I do a key press from excel VBA window, it is not being called. I need to capture a keypress event in excel VBA. I don't know what I am missing here.

Edit:
The same code works in Excel 2010. It doesn't work with Excel 2016 and Excel 2022. So it should be a office 2016 and greater version problem.

```
#region Keyboard Event Handler

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private KeyBoardHookProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        private IntPtr SetHook(KeyBoardHookProc proc)
        {          
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                0, 0);    
        }

        private delegate IntPtr KeyBoardHookProc(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
              ....
        }
```

Comment: Quote from docs "A 32-bit DLL cannot be injected into a 64-bit process, and a 64-bit DLL cannot be injected into a 32-bit process" might possibly affect things?

Comment: All are in 64 bit process. Excel is also 64 bit.

Comment: It might well be that Excel routes its keyboard events through a different window, not through its main window messageloop?

Comment: Consider using the [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) instead of a LowLevel Keyboard hook.

Comment: @cha A low-level hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. No DLLs get loaded into any processes. Indeed, there may not even be a DLL involved.

Comment: @ren A low-level hook is called long before the target window is even identified. Whatever message processing any given thread is performing will not have any effect on events that happened earlier in time.